# Ubuntu software center crashes every time I try to open

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center

SystemError: E:Encountered a section with no Package: header,

```
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This is the problem I encounter when I try to open ubuntu software center please help me out to fix it and make software center work as normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the file:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN
```

and update the the package database again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can also remove the entire folder: `/var/lib/apt/lists`

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this enter from the terminal:

```
  sudo apt-get remove softwate-center
  sudo apt-get install software-center
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: sairamakrishna@Krishna:~$ sudo apt-get remove softwate-center
[sudo] password for sairamakrishna: 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
sairamakrishna@Krishna:~$                                                                                               It shows like this

Comment: delete the sources.list file and enter setting and update and hatch the upper chanorinal sourece and it might work fine this way.